# Opening links in a table inside a div in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created html page as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body bgcolor="#EBF5FB">
  <h1 align="center">SLA Monitor Reports </h1>
  <div id="link" align="center">

    <table cellpadding="25px" border=1>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <a href="https://serv.sxp.nova.corp/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content!2fcom.nova.pct!2fplatform_add_ons!2fcom.nova.ip.bi!2fiViews!2fcom.sap.ip.bi.bex?BOOKMARK=CU4A95OJ17A355B2112ML30G6" target="_blank"><img src="\\server\server$\23185\Downloads\1Google.png" alt="Ticket Aging" style="width:200px"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://serv.sxp.nova.corp/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/pcd!3aportal_content!2fcom.nova.pct!2fplatform_add_ons!2fcom.nova.ip.bi!2fiViews!2fcom.sap.ip.bi.bex?BOOKMARK=CU4A95OJ17A355B2112ML30G6" target="_blank"><img src="\\server\server$\23185\Downloads\1Google.png" alt="Ticket Aging" style="width:200px"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to display the https://......  link's content under the table in the same page using `<div>`.

IFrames didn't help as it's a secured link.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Your question is unclear!

Comment: can you try this $(yourDiv).load("yourLink");

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link table td a").click(function(e){
    $("#link").next().load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7uj8tk2y/

Comment: hi...the above code looks fine but how do i display it in the same page using div tag

Comment: Its should work in the same page. Its cant work in fiddle, Have you access that links?

Comment: Thanks for your reply the requirement is that the content of the link for example https://www.google.co.in should display below the table.I used a div tag below the table but no idea how to redirect the target of the link to this div